# How to convert date String array into string using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

below is my JSON format which i got via dynamic data

```
{"range":["2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z","2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z"]}
```

and how can i want to  convert this into  below format

```
range(20180723,20180723)
```

below is my code :

```
var data:Date[] = {"range":["2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z","2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z"]}

  for(let i=0;i<=data.range.length;i++){
       console.log(,data.range[i]);
       }
```

Comment: "below format"...the format shown looks like the syntax for a call to a function, not a data structure. Also the question title doesn't seem to bear any relation to that either. What on earth is a "normal" string, as opposed to any other kind of string? It's unclear what you actually want as your output?

Comment: As a random guess, maybe you're really asking how to get each item inside the "range" array and place them all into a comma-separated list? In which case: `var output = "";
for (let i = 0; i < data.range.length; i++) {
  output += (output == "" ? "" : ", ") + data.range[i];
}
console.log(output);` - see http://jsfiddle.net/3tscwqdr/2/

Comment: i tried to execute ur solution but it is displaying this in below format 2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z, 2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a crack at this based on what I think you mean.

So in order for us to convert the string date to the format, you would like we can go about this multiple ways. The easiest way is to use a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) or [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). These libraries can take inputs like `2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z` and convert them to a `Date` object. You can then use the date object to get the relevant values, for example;

```
const dateString = "2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z";
let dateObject = moment(dateString, "YYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ").toDate();
let finalDateString = dateObject.getFullYear().toString()+dateObject.getMonth().toString()+dateObject.getDays().toString();
```

You can read up more about how to achieve this using the moment.js library in their [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Alternatively, you can split the date string at the `T` and replace the `-` now contained in the first array item in order to achieve this as well;

```
const dateString = "2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z";
const outputDateString = dateString.split("T")[0].replace(/-/g,"");
```

You can read more about the `String.prototype.split()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and more about the `String.prototype.replace()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) if you're interested.

Both these approaches would work and can be easily implemented in your already existing for loop e.g.

```
let data = {"range":["2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z","2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z"]}

let output = "range("
for(let i=0;i<=data.range.length;i++){
   output += data.range[i].split("T")[0].replace(/-/g,"")+(i===0 ? "," : ")");
}
console.log(range) //"range(20180723,20180723)"
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the key point please check the question i updated the data having Date[]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var obj = {"range":["2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z","2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z"]};
for(var k in obj){
  var str = '';
  var temp = obj[k].map(d => {
    var m = (new Date(d).getMonth()+1) <= 9? '0' + (new Date(d).getMonth()+1):''+(new Date(d).getMonth()+1);
    d = new Date(d).getFullYear().toString() + m + new Date(d).getDate();
    return d;
  });
  str = k + '(' + temp.join(',') + ')';
  console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: it is string array i unable to apply that

Comment: @Devpop "It is string array I am unable to apply that"...what does unable to mean? You get an error? Unexpected behaviour? It works in the snippet above. Anyway it doesn't finish up as an array...it's converted into a string in the last-but-one line! This is a neat solution and deserves an upvote

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the key point please check the question i updated the data having Date[]

Answer (score 0):

Split on T, take the first part, remove the dashes. Would be one approach

Comment: could u post syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired string by `data.range[i].split("T")[0].replace(/-/g,'')`

May be you want something like this:

```js
var data = {
  "range": ["2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z", "2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z"]
}

var result = [];// for ouput
var strKey=Object.keys(data)[0];//key of main object.i.e. range
var objData=data[strKey];//value of key


for (let i = 0; i < objData.length; i++) {
     result.push(getFormattedDate(objData[i]));
}

var prepend=strKey+"(";//prepended 
var postpend=")";//postpender
result =prepend+result.join(",") + postpend;
console.log(result);


function getFormattedDate(date) {
    return date.split("T")[0].replace(/-/g,''); 
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the key point please check the question i updated the data having Date[]

Comment: var data:Date[] = {"range":["2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z","2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z"]}; is not correct.it having compile time error.


     Correct is :  **var data:Date[] = [new Date("2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z"),new Date("2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z")];**

you should learn typeScript basics

Comment: Yeah..I can unable to loop it and data format is coming directly through a third party pluin not from my side from that 3rd party plugin I'm getting data like that and I cannot apply new date function like that to the dynamic data

Comment: change **data:Date[]**  to **data:any[]** or **data:any** <=== this will work in my logic

Comment: it has to be Date[] only as per https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker   compentt in that bsRangeValue: Date[]; thats why with any i sorted it out but with Date[] only i unable to sort it

Comment: var data2:Date[] = [];
        var data:any = {"range":["2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z","2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z"]};
        for (let i = 0; i < data.range.length; i++) {
            data2.push(new Date(data.range));
        }

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements properly then this small snippet will do your job with your existing codeblock. You just need the to split the datetime value by `T` using [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and replace the `-` using [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var data = {"range":["2018-07-22T15:03:26.861Z","2018-07-23T16:03:26.861Z"]}
var expected =[];
for(var i=0;i<data.range.length;i++){
 expected.push(data.range[i].split('T')[0].replace(/-/g,""))
}
console.log('range('+ expected.join(',') +')');
```

Comment: the data which i gave to you is string array it wont work

Comment: @Devpop "it won't work"....run the snippet above, you'll see it definitely works :-)

Comment: @Devpop have you tried my added snippet? please "Run the snippet" first, it creates the same result that you want as output. Hope this will help :)

Comment: yeah tried and sorry i forgot to mention the key point please check the question i updated the data having Date[]